# Recompute directive for hiding elements after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Good day guys,

I have a situation where I want to show some UI elements on the basis of if session is active or not.

The approach I have taken is using directive. It works great however when the person has logged in successfully the directives are not computed.

Previously I was using like this:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-hide="vm.model.currentUser.id !== 0">
```

To refactor well, I have moved the logic of check at directive level and calling it as:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" !ap-valid-login-session>
```

Two questions:

- Is this approach is correct or is there any other better way to do?
- If this approach is correct then how can I make sure that directive is recomputed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `!` in html. So, the second snippet will not work. If, however, you remove the `!` and move all logic into the directive where you add and remove the `hidden` class on the element, this could work.

However, the coding style that I use tries to avoid manipulating html attributes and css classes inside of a directive.  This is mixing the presentation layer with the business logic layer and is bad separation of concerns.

Instead, I would use the first snippet with a small change. I would extract the angular expression into a method call like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-hide="isValidUser()">
```

and in the directive:

```
scope.isValidUser = function() { return vm.model.currentUser.id !== 0; }
```

The benefits here are:

1. More semantically meaningful html
2. business logic separated from presentation
3. Easier to write unit tests for

Comment: I agree...the first way is more correct, but in a method is better.

Comment: ! is the typo in my snippet. It is working once when the whole page is compiled by ng. so my question remain the same that once I login how can calculate directive again. anyhow I thought directives are meant to manipulate html so if I can separate then definitely A+. Now when you say in the directive ... are you using the scope of a directive, if so then ng-hide belongs to angular then why do I have to define directive.  If you then talking about controller scope then I affraid if I want to define isValidUser for different controller.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the function needs to be in the scope of that <ul> element. In this case, it would be a controller. If `isValidUser` is complex enough and shared across several scopes, then you will want to extract it into its own service.  And each controller that uses it will use DI to inject it and then add the function to its scope.